# How to get all nodes of a content type as header menu item?

Tags: routes, nodes

I want to get all nodes of Article type added dynamically to header menu. Any module that can do it for me?

Comment: Use a combination of om_maximenu (for the dropdown menu) and views (that can be displayed as blocks in the menu).

Comment: I would just use a view (each item can link to the relevant node), no need for an actual "menu" at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure content type to create menu items. So look at content type configuration.
It will dynamically create menu items when new node is created.